# Homeomorphism onto a closed subset of a scheme that isn't a closed immersion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

More precisely, is there a map of schemes $X$ --> $Y$ such that $f$ gives a homeomorphism between $X$ and a closed subset of $Y$, but the corresponding map on sheaves is not surjective?

Comment: The topology is not enough to determine the scheme structure in general as show the counteramples of Rebecca and of Matt. On the positive direction, you could have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12767/when-two-k-varieties-with-the-same-underlying-topological-spaces-isomorphic/12788

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, for example if $K \subset L$ is an inclusion fields, then the induced map
Spec $L \to $ Spec $K$ is a homeomorphism (both source and target are single points),
but the induced map on sheaves is the given inclusion of $K$ into $L$, which is 
surjective only if $K = L$.

For another example, let $X'\to Y$ be a closed immersion of schemes over ${\bar{\mathbb F}}\_p$, and let $X \to X'$ be the relative Frobenius morphism.
Then $X\to X'$ is a homeomorphism on underlying topological spaces but is not an isomorphism of schemes, and so the composite $X\to Y$ is a closed embedding on underlying spaces but not a closed immersion of schemes.

As one last example, let $X'$ be the cuspidal cubic given by $y^2  = x^3$ in the affine
plane $Y$ (over $\mathbb C$, say), and let $X$ be the normalization of $X'$ (which is just
the affine line).  Then $X \to X'$ is a homeomorphism on underlying spaces, but is not
an isomorphism of schemes.  The composite $X \to Y$ is thus not a closed immersion,
but induces a closed embedding of underlying topological spaces.

Comment: In the second example, is $X$ the normalisation of $X'$ (as in the third example)?

Comment: I suspect that $X \to X'$ is meant to be the relative Frobenius map. But I hope we'll get a confirmation soon.

Comment: David is correct; I've added this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example: Consider the morphism $f:\text{Spec} k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)\rightarrow \text{Spec} k$ corresponding to the inclusion $k\hookrightarrow k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$.  More generally, you can get lots of examples from non-reducedness.